# How to do a JSON to SOAP Transform in java?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

Most of the current documents are with reference to SOAP-to-JSON, I was hoping whether there are any reference material or tutorials to transform JSON response objects to SOAP service.

Or is there a way to convert JSON to soap using AWS lambda?

Attached is the Josn and also the expected sample Soap after conversion.

```
 { 
  "successFlag": true, 
  "message": "Execution Successful", 
  "id": 2, 
  "additionalParams": { 
    "inputRequest": { 
      "customerId": "123456", 
      "customerName": "Public", 
      "phoneNumber": "123456789"
                    }
                      }
  }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns="urn:core_2018_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns2:tokenPassport>
            <account>******</account>
        </ns2:tokenPassport>
        <ns2:preferences>
            <ns2:warningAsError>false</ns2:warningAsError>
        </ns2:preferences>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:update>
            <ns2:record
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns6:Customer" internalId="123456">  
                <ns6:customFieldList>
                    <customField xsi:type="SelectCustomFieldRef" scriptId="custentitystatus">
                        <value internalId="2"/>
                    </customField>
                    <customField xsi:type="StringCustomFieldRef" scriptId="custentitymessage">
                        <value>Execution Successful</value>
                    </customField>
                </ns6:customFieldList>
            </ns2:record>
        </ns2:update>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the (excellent) JSON-Java library from json.org then

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

`toString` can take a second argument to provide the name of the XML root node.

This library is also able to convert XML to JSON using `XML.toJSONObject(java.lang.String string)`

Check the [Javadoc](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html)

Link to the [the github repository](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

*POM*
I advise you to look for later versions

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you but i need to convert a JSON into soap not xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this librarie `org.json`

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.*;
public class SimpleTesting{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException{
        String jsonStr = "{student : { age:30, name : Kumar, technology : Java } }";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        String xml = XML.toString(json);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```